# How to implement dynamic background image in swift

Tags: ios, image, dynamic, swift

I would like to implement the same behaviour that the start page with "true motion backgrounds". When you tilt the phone the background image move a bit which makes it look 3D and "real".

This what I would like in my application start page.

How do I make this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [`UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInterpolatingMotionEffect_class/index.html).

You can create one for each axis, create a group, and add the motion effect group to the `UIImageView` in the background.

```
let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -50
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 50

let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -50
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 50

let motionEffectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()
motionEffectGroup.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]

imageView.addMotionEffect(motionEffectGroup)
```

Thus, as you tilt it about the y-axis, the image will move left and right. As you tilt about the x-axis, the image will move up and down.

[image: from developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW14]
(Image taken from the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/HandlingAccelerometerEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH22-SW1]).)

Comment: Looks great. Is it possible to combine this with sensoring when user tilt the iphone. Tilt to the right and move the image to the left and vice versa.

Comment: I don't follow you. With the above code, as you tilt the device left and right about the y-axis, the image will already move right and left, respectively. (It combines this with rotations about the x-axis resulting in the image moving up and down, too, completing the illusion of some depth as the user moves the device around in their hands.)

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I did read it through. I will surely try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Objective-C** (Incase if anyone still working with Obj-C in 2020)

```
// Vertical effect
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = 
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] 
  initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
             type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

// horizontal effect 
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = 
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] 
  initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"     
             type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

// Combine both effect
UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];

// Add combine effects to your ImageView OR UIView
[yourImageView addMotionEffect:group];
```